# Code not hitting the server side

Tags: android

I am trying to send an image from android mobile to .NET server, android code:-

```
package com.example.imageupload;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    InputStream mInputStream;
    String mUrl                                 =   "http://10.0.2.2:49246/WebSite1/";

    // Async task helps to run network operations in Non-UI thread..
    private class GetRouteInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
           try 
           {    
                //resize the bitmap...
                String path                             =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/android.jpg";
                Bitmap bitmap                           =   resizeBitMapImage1(path, 800, 600);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream            =   new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,30, stream);

                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy          =   new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs =   new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_data", Base64.encodeToString(stream.toByteArray(),Base64.NO_WRAP)));

                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
                bitmap.recycle();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FileName", "TrueSeeImage"));

                HttpClient httpclient                   =   new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost                       =   new HttpPost(mUrl);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response1                  =   httpclient.execute(httppost);

                Log.i("response", response1.toString());
                Log.i("DataUploaderOffline_Image ","Status--> Completed");
            }
           catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("SvcMgr", "Service Execution Failed!", e);
                }

                finally {
                    Log.i("SvcMgr", "Service Execution Completed...");
                }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Log.i("SvcMgr", "Service Execution Cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.i("SvcMgr", "Service Execution cycle completed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new GetRouteInfo().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{

        String res          =   "";
        StringBuffer buffer =   new StringBuffer();
        mInputStream        =   response.getEntity().getContent();
        int contentLength   =   (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
        System.out.println("contentLength : " + contentLength);
        if (contentLength < 0){
        }
        else{
               byte[] data  =   new byte[512];
               int len      =   0;
               try
               {
                   while (-1 != (len = mInputStream.read(data)) )
                   {
                       buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
                   }
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               try
               {
                   mInputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
               }
               catch (IOException e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               res          =   buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string…..

               System.out.println("Result : " + res);
        }
        return res;
   }

    // Method to compress image..
    // Input  : filepath, target width, target height..
    // Output : resized bitmap image..
    public static Bitmap resizeBitMapImage1(String filePath, int targetWidth,int targetHeight) {

        Bitmap bitMapImage = null;

        try {

            Options options                 =   new Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds      =   true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
            double sampleSize               =   0;
            Boolean scaleByHeight           =   Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math
                                                .abs(options.outWidth - targetWidth);
            if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 1638) {
                sampleSize = scaleByHeight ? options.outHeight / targetHeight
                        : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
                sampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2d,Math.floor(Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
            }
            options.inJustDecodeBounds      =   false;
            options.inTempStorage           =   new byte[128];
            while (true) {
                try {
                    options.inSampleSize    =   (int) sampleSize;
                    bitMapImage             =   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    try {
                        sampleSize          =   sampleSize * 2;
                    } catch (Exception ex1) {
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return bitMapImage;
    }
}
```

And the .NET part is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Data")))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Data"));
        }

        if (Request.InputStream.Length != 0 && Request.InputStream.Length < 32768)
        {

            Response.ContentType     =   "text/plain";
            string c                 =   Request.Form["image_data"];
            string FileName          =   Request.Form["FileName"];
            byte[] bytes             =   Convert.FromBase64String(c);

            System.Drawing.Image image;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                image           =   System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                image.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                String Fname    =   FileName + ".jpeg";
                image.Save(Server.MapPath("save\\" + Fname), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access the server side code from android browser it hits the server side code in the debug mode, but when I run the program from eclipse or debug the program from eclipse, it doesn't hit the code in the visual studio. What could be the reason?